# How to use ngrok in the boilerplate code of actions on google?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, ngrok

I would like to use the "boilerplate"-structure (see github), use firebase for productive code, but ngrok during development. How can I combine it?

https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-webhook-boilerplate-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js

```js
'use strict';

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  conv.close('Hello, World!');
  // Complete your fulfillment logic and
  // send a response when the function is done executing
});

exports.yourAction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Does this help ... https://medium.com/@antonyharfield/dialogflow-web-hooks-how-to-develop-locally-and-deploy-to-cloud-functions-48839919e998

Comment: It would, but I am not quite sure how to handle  "exports.yourAction = functions.https.onRequest(app);" together with express without restructering my whole code.

Comment: The best option is either to have a constant at the top to switch the export mechanism, or comment out whichever implementation you have.